# create million table in a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization

I wanna create a million double column tables.. well I tried to create using java which took some 100 mbs of data converted to 7Gbs and took 20hrs to complete it... I am using postgre sql before which I tried mysql, mysql is even worse .. Is there any way to create this much amount of tables using less space and time?
will horizontal partitioning work well ?

I am trying to index RDF data for fast execution, Idea is to index rdf data using rdbms and transform sparql query to sql query, well RDF is collection of resources in form of triples subject, predicate, object, existing methods use predicate tables means, for each predicate, subject and object are stored, amount of predicates are very less as compared to other 2. So querying requires joining of these predicate tables in order to get results which are of order of 100mbs in flat files.I was trying of creating subject tables 4 fast execution

Comment: why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: maybe you could tell us why you want that, and people could give you advice on a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Clearly you shouldn't try to create a 'double column' table.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a million tables in your database, you're doing it wrong.

Tables are intended to represent structurally and conceptually different data. And I refuse to believe that you're operating with a million different concepts in your application.

Sometimes, beginners believe they should create a table per user, for example. But "a user" is one concept, and you store the same information for each user (name, email, username, password, for example), so it ought to be *one* table, where each user is just a separate row.

It sounds like you're making a similar mistake, perhaps not with users, but with some other abstraction which you have a lot of instances of. Each instance should be a row in one single table.

If you describe to us what it is you're trying to store in a database, we can almost certainly help you figure out how it *should* be mapped to tables.

**Edit**
after reading your comments (which should really be edited into the question itself), here are my thoughts:

If all the data is structured the same way (as triples), you could simply store everything in a single table with three columns, and then add the necessary indexes for efficient lookups.

If all the predicates are known in advance, you *could* make a table per predicate, but I'm not really sure how much sense that would make, even.

The cleanest option would probably be to have 4 tables:
 `(id, subject)`, `(id, predicate)` , `(id, object)`,`(subjectid, predicateid, objectid)`.

Comment: thanks for ur replay, I was thinking very naive way, I am trying to index RDF data for fast execution, Idea is to index rdf data using rdbms and transform sparql query to sql query, well RDF is collection of resources in form of triples subject, predicate, object, existing methods use predicate tables means, for each predicate, subject and object are stored, amount of predicates are very less as compared to other 2. So querying requires joining of these predicate tables in order to get results which are of order of 100mbs in flat files.I was trying of creating subject tables 4 fast execution.

Comment: As I already specified in previous post, existing methods are using predicate tables .. the problem is if we have 10 joins on a predicate table it will take hrs to give results back. Ex query (?p livesIn ?l) so p is person and l is location joing with (?p hasName kunal) so from result of first query I want to check which person have name kunal .. and some further joins.. My idea is to serch for a predicate in subject or object table rather than to search a ssubject in predicate table.

Comment: @kunal: that sounds like a bad idea, for a number of reasons. It's just not how relational databases are intended to work. But remember that string lookups (I assume that all three fields are strings) are fairly expensive. Look at my last suggestion, which could potentially speed things up a lot (instead of looking for all triples where the subject is kunal, you can look up the kunal once in the subject table, and then get a subject-id you can search for in the table of triples (which for each triple, just stores an id into each of the subject, predicate and object tables)

Answer (score 1):

Database tables use up quite a bit of space for managing their indexes, schema and reserving disc space.

In most cases you'll be better off with a single table that has 20 million rows than you will having a million tables with 20 rows.

If the 20 million row approach got too big you could then use vertical partitioning to make it perform better.

I do think you're mainly going to succeed in giving Stack overflow users a mass annurism trying to work out why you need to do what you're asking :)