# Performance of postgresql with large numbers of tables (EG: 1 million tables)?

Tags: postgresql, filesystems, max, ext4

What is the largest number of tables that can be within a single pgsql database while still retaining good performance, given that pgsql stores 1 file per table on the filesystem and searches the pg_catalog for every query to do query planning?

EG: Can pgsql deal with 1 million tables within a single database? Assume that the filesystem used is ext4 and each table contained very little data, so the overage disk storage size isn't an issue. The issue really comes from (1) impact of having 1 million files on the filesystem and (2) impact of having 1 million entries in pg_catalog.

From this thread (2005), http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/GENERAL-Maximum-number-of-tables-per-database-and-slowness-td1853836.html - it is said below (but I do not how much of this is still applicable these days):

Benjamin Arai wrote:

> What is the current maximum number of tables per database?  Also, does 
>   having more tables slow down performance in any way?

For most cases, the answer is no. However, once you get near 6 figure 
table counts, pg_catalog ends up being pretty massive. The problem is 
that the query planner must check pg_catalog for every query to see what 
indexes are available, what the statistics & value distributions are, 
etc. in order to build the optimal plan. At some point, a really large 
pg_catalog can begin to bog down your system.

...

William Yu <[hidden email]> writes:

> Benjamin Arai wrote:
>
> > What is the current maximum number of tables per database?  Also, does 
> >     having more tables slow down performance in any way?
>
> For most cases, the answer is no. However, once you get near 6 figure 
>   table counts, pg_catalog ends up being pretty massive.

You also have to think about the performance implications of having tens 
of thousands of files in your database directory.  While some newer 
filesystems aren't fazed by that particularly, a lot of 'em bog down on 
lookups when there are more than a few thousand entries in a directory.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to keep a million files in a single directory. You can use [`CREATE TABLESPACE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html) to arrange space in a different directory or on a different disk.  I don't know anything about pg_catalog internals, but I can *imagine* how it might narrow the search by tablespace first, which could significantly reduce search time.

But that's different from the possible problems of having a million files in the filesystem in general, or with the actual (not imagined) issues with pg_catalog.

Should be easy to do a simple (and possibly misleading) test. Use your favorite scripting language to create a million tables, each having five or six columns.

Comment: I doubt it.  Tablespaces are internal storage mechnanisms.  Schemas are more likely to be helpful.

Comment: Since the tablespaces aren't specified in the query, how does it now which to search under?

Comment: PostgreSQL stores the tablespace name with the object name. For example, the tablespace a particular table is stored in is in the [system catalog pg_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/view-pg-tables.html).

Comment: Right, but how does it know which tablespace to search?

Comment: By looking up the table name in pg_tables.

Comment: But once you know the oid in pg_class (which is the system catalog that stores this), why would you need to query on the tablespace to narrow things down?  The table + schema is plenty specific.

Comment: Schema and table names are logical, not physical. They tell PostgreSQL *what* you want (logical). They don't tell PostgreSQL where to find what you want on disk (physical). That's what tablespaces do. If you create a million tables (logical), by default all your tables will end up in a single directory on disk (physical). Schemas (logical) don't change that. Create 256 unique tablespaces (physical), and you can reduce the number of tables in each directory to about 4000.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by searching by tablespace first and what impact that has on search times.  Are you talking about scanning directories or system catalogs?

Comment: Directories. The tablespace column tells PostgreSQL where a table is stored on disk. (But it uses NULL for the default tablespace.)

Comment: Right.  In that case there might be a modest performance gain but the specifics would not be the way Postgres handles it but rather the internals of the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

In general, according to those I know of who have used very large numbers of tables (in many thousands), planning overhead goes up as the number of tables in the db goes up.  Those I have known who have had this as a problem have had to find solutions for this problem but have not specified to me what those solutions were.  What happens is the database planner, in order to decide the best way to execute a query must look up information based on the tables and columns, so this requires searching for data in system catalogs that become more and more bloated over time.  This impacts every query at plan time.

The basic issue is that when planning you have to be taking into account data on tables (requiring looking up stuff on tables) and columns, and columns.  Interestingly pg_class has an index on oid and one on relnamespace, but not one on relname and you can't easily create one.  The only indexes in the system tables are UNIQUE constraints and so I don't see how, other than altering the system catalogs (at the source level or giving you permission to do this) that you can solve this problem.

I would also expect performance to degrade slowly so you can't just put a hard limit on this.  Consequently it depends on acceptable performance on a given workload.

If you have that many tables, I would look at seeing how many of them could be broken off into other databases first.

tl; dr:  Expect performance issues with very large numbers of tables.  Expect to have to be creative to resolve them.

Comment: Databases with large numbers of tables usually have them because they're being programmatically created. That is, planning isn't particularly relevant; tables are being used as the object level of granularity for naturally relational, but atomic (with in the domain) things. I'm thinking of things like result sets for batch processes that may have different shapes, where efficient access to recent data is far more important than dumping many billions of rows into a single overly-wide table.

Comment: Planning being the database planner, which has to look up information on the tables.  I am editing this to make it a little more clear.

Comment: @AaronBertrand actually, I think Chris's answer has been improved by my comment interpreting "planning" in one way instead of another.

Comment: @BarryKelly, actually, anyone knowing anything about database performance (including anyone asking this question) will know what "planning overhead" is in this context.  The improvements in the answer are solely useful for people approaching a question like this as a curiosity, lacking the background knowledge sufficient to make a working solution.

Comment: But we all have to start somewhere, so it is an improvement, just not for folks asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/197-Self-inflicted-pain.html) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840551/create-million-table-in-a-database) including the comments shed some more light on this issue.

To answer your question: It depends on the "while still retaining good performance" part. What do you *exactly* consider "still good performance"? And with *exactly* what workload?

Let me rephrase your question: How much toothache can a human endure? Same answer!

But in both cases the **real** question is: Why would you really care? The better solution in both cases is to take actions to remove the cause and to get into a painless condition ASAP.